# Divide huge file java

Tags: java

I have big file more than 1 GB and I want to search for the occurrence of a certain word.
so I want to task over several threads where each thread will handle a portion of the file.

what is the best approach to do this, I thought about read the file into several buffers of fixed size and pass each thread a buffer.

is there a better way to do this

[EDIT] i want to  execut each thread on different device

Comment: Just asking: have you considered just calling `grep`? It's highly optimized and probably would outperform your implementation, even while single-threaded.

Comment: Why do you think it will be faster?  A disk can only read from one place at a time.

Comment: Have you benchmarked the time that a single threaded approach takes for this particular situation?

Comment: I want to do that because i want to process that file in parallel computing

Comment: Why do you want to process it using parallel processing?

Comment: @stark that is not true at all, specially in RAID systems and SSD.

Comment: @PeterMmm I specifically said "disk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ByteBuffer, say on a RandomAccessFile would be feasible for files < 2 GB (2<sup>31</sup>).

The general solution would be to use [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29), with its `MappedByteBuffer`.

With several buffers one must take care to have overlapping buffers, so the word can be found on buffer boundaries.

Comment: would this load block of the file in memory or just pointer to it in hard disk?

Comment: Modern OSes support 'paging' by which a computer can store and retrieve data from secondary storage for use in main memory. Memory-mapping (MappedByteBuffer) is a kind of paging. If you use MappedByteBuffer, your OS maps the file content onto a memory area and you can access the data as if it were a byte array. For big files, memory-mapping is faster than reading by FileInputStream. Dividing a job into threads without consideration about Disk I/O and Network I/O would not bring you any performance gain. Also, using threads on a machine with only one CPU core would 'degrade' performance.

Comment: @TakahikoKawasaki explained all aspects; a MappedByteBuffer is fast; for a find-one-occurrence search threads could still improve speed - with programming overhead. For a find-all-occurrences threads are restricted by disk I/O.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks so much for your answer.after reading the oracle docs about FileChannel class i found the solution for what i'm looking for .

Answer (score 0):

Reading the thread into the buffers will probably take just as long as just doing the search (the extra processing required to search is tiny compared to the time needed to read the file off the disk - and in fact it may well be able to do that processing in the time it would otherwise just be waiting for data).

Searching multiple locations in the file at once will be very slow on most storage systems.

The real question comes as to whether you are only searching each file once or if you frequently search them. If only once then you have no real choice but to scan the file and take the time. If you are doing it frequently then you could consider indexing the contents somehow.

Comment: what I am trying to do is to load a block of the file into memory, pass that block to a thread that will be executed on a different device and so on till I load the whole file, this is an exercise in a parallel programming course

Comment: Then what you have in mind will work - although you will not gain performance by doing it.

Comment: why not ? the parts of the file will be searched in parallel , won't that give some performance gain over a sequential search ?

Comment: Amdahl's Law - if you only speed up the part of a process that was already fast, you don't gain anything because the slow part is still slow.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) MapReduce.

If you want to execute threads (= divided tasks) on different devices, the input file should be on a distributed file system such as HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System). MapReduce is a mechanism to divide one job into multiple tasks and run them on different machines in parallel.

Comment: I have that file on one machine but processing would be on parallel machine it's for learning purpose

Comment: If you executed tasks on different devices although the input file is on one machine, each task would suffer from network I/O. So, from a viewpoint of performance, it's not a good approach. However, if you just want to learn parallel computing, the first step is to determine the way to share the input file among your computing machines. NFS is one of legacy ways. Then, each task thread, to be exact, each task 'process', should open the input file, jump to the position which is assigned to the task, and start counting. Note that 'threads' are running in one 'process' by definition.